# Rapid, Ajaxian and Indexable Java Web App?

Tags: java, ajax, web-applications, search-engine, rad

I am search for a Java web app with the following characteristics:

- Allow Rapid Development
- Has built-in support for AJAX
- Indexable by search engines (i.e. the output is HTML not JS)
- Provide clean URLs (example.com/path/path/file)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My recent search for a framework led me to [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/overview).

### Rapid

- In development mode, code is automatically recompiled when you make changes.  Just reload the webpage to see your changes
- Useful error messages:

[image]

### AJAX

- Includes jQuery as it's javascript library
- Makes [ReST](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/routes#rest) easy
- Source code includes an example Chat application demostrating  how to do Comet, which turned out to be way simpler than I expected

### Output

- [Templating engine](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/templates) can serve multiple output types.  You can provide templates in html, json, and txt format by default and it will serve whichever version is requested by client.

### Routing

- [Routes file](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/routes#syntax) makes it easy to make your routes look however you want.
- Template engine includes [actions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/templates#Actionsor) that are automatically translated into urls according to your specifications in the routes file, so you don't have to go around updating your internal links.

Lots of other cool stuff too.  So far it's been a joy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) ;-) - http://www.springsource.org/roo